# Как вынуть и изменить нужную строку?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть цифровые данные, например: "Яблоки: 20", "Груши: 50". Числа эти меняются. Эти данные я решил хранить в базе SQLite. Но как вынуть нужные мне данные, к примеру по нажатию кнопки вынуть Груши, а по нажатию другой - изменить значение Яблок?

Comment: Создаете таблицу с двумя колонками: "Название", "Количество". А дальше стандартные запросы `select`, `update`.

Comment: Если нужно хранить только такие данные, то есть смысл посмотреть в сторону NoSql БД типа key-value.

Answer (score 2):

Через

```
SELECT column_cont FROM nameTable WHERE name = 'Яблоки';

UPDATE column_cont = 40 FROM nameTable WHERE name = 'Яблоки';
```

Где

```
column_cont - ячейка с количество едениц
name  - имя продукта
nameTable - имя таблицы
```

Увидел тег `Java`, учи `Spring JDBC`. Там в 2 счета сделаешь подобное.